# Using kirchoff's laws to solve a circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

The image shown above is for a complex circuit where every resistance in it equals 4Ω, and I want to determine the total current intensity ( the intensity of the current getting out of the battery Itot.) could you please help me because I solved it many times by kirchoff's laws and I got different values in every time. The values I got were variable for examble I got 6.6667A and another time I got 3.11A and another I got 16.5A.
Could you please tell me how to solve it or if one of my answers was correct.
Remember all the values I mentioned were for Itot.[image]
That is one of my works, I would complete it here, 
Equations are: (1) 15=i₁−i₂+i (2) i₂=2i−3i₁ (3) 0=4i₂−2i+i₁
 From equation (2): 15=4i₁−i-----> that would be(4), and 0=6i−11i₁--->(5)
                 (4) times 11: 165=44i₁−11i
                 (5) times 4 : 0=−44i₁+24i
Adding the last two equations to easch other results in i=12.69A, and i in my equations represented Itot. Where is the wrong, please guide me and correct it!

Comment: Can you show us some of your work? It would help us figure out where you're going wrong. We usually don't like to give direct answers to homework questions.

Comment: You need to use both Kirchhoff Laws to solve the circuit. What do you get?

Comment: I edited the question and added one of my works, please check it and tell me your opinions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show your work to see how you have gone wrong.

An easy way to check if you are correct is to just plug the values into the circuit.

Itot = 12.69A

**Edit**
Your work just showed up. Your first loop should go all the way through the bottom area and not just on the left side.

Also the current in the circled resistor is just I3-I2.  All of your mesh current labels are off.  You have I3 written in as I2 in the top right ... but I2 is the mesh current on the left-top side.

I fixed some problems with your graph.  Stop trying to force the other variables into loop currents which are not directly influencing them; just write the simple 3 equations first and then cancel variables.

[image: pic updated]

Comment: I just edited the question and showed one of my work, and I got a result resembles to yours, it was 12.69A. I had many solutions for this question, so please check my answer in the question details. And tell me your opinion. Sorry if it wasn't clear but I couldn't add more photos because I don't have the reputations needed.

Comment: Would that make a difference?! I mean changing the loop.

Comment: Well your loop is invalid right now since you just end it in the center of the hole.

Comment: For the case of loop 1, yes that is exactly what I assumed and ment by the graph, but why didn't you complete with I, I₁ and I₂, instead of changing them to I, I2 and I3?

Comment: Because it is a lot easier and more foolproof to just write the equations out as simply as possible and solve from there.  As you have shown you got three different answers each time you solved it; all wrong (but one off by a factor of 10).

Comment: Another clue that all three of your answers are incorrect is that even 3.33A (your lowest answer) through a 40 Ohm resistor creates a ~120V voltage drop; which is about twice as large as the voltage supply in the circuit.

Comment: Oh, Ok But the resistance is only 4 Ohms.

Comment: Oh, then your 12.69A answer is correct.  I misread the original question and solved for all R = 40Ohms